# Regex must match two conditions

Tags: regex

I've been trying to match lines on two requirements but can't seem to combine the two to get matches.

I have to have **S OZN** and then do a search for **CME 2 # 1 # 1**. I tried using **S OZN (CME 2 \d+ 1 \d+ 1)** where # is a number typically with 7 numbers but no matches.

Some sample data. I've highlighted my match positions in bold. These aren't the entire lines. The lines are from a log4net file. I've shaved off the timestamps to fit this page.

**S OZN** T$ 116700 T$ 123600 12/27/2013 1449025 3559247 0.015625 **CME 2 3451471 1 3451026 1**

**S OZB** U3 116702 U3 123602 12/27/2013 1449012 3532393 0.015625 **CME 2 3451048 1 3451491 -1**

**S OZN** T$ 116700 T$ 123600 12/27/2013 1449025 3578191 0.015625 **CME 2 3538674 1 3538771 1**

**S OZN** T$ 116700 T$ 123600 12/27/2013 1449025 3612539 0.015625 **CME 2 3451476 1 3451036 1**

**S OZN** T$ 116700 T$ 123600 12/27/2013 1449025 3559770 0.015625 **CME 2 3451193 1 3451519 -2**

Comment: What is the language/tool are you using? Put it on the tags

Comment: I'm not using it in any language. I'm running it in BareTailPro's search module.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a bunch of text between **S OZN** and **CME** which you need to skip over. Are you interested in grabbing the two numbers?

```
S OZN(.*?)CME\s2\s(\d+)\s1\s(\d+)
```

might do the job (I haven't checked it... (.*?) is supposed to be a "non-greedy" match of anything but not CME). If it doesn't work, and there is a fixed length of text to skip over, try

```
S OZN(.{57})CME\s2\s(\d+)\s1\s(\d+)
```

if I counted the length correctly. $2 and $3 should be the values you're going after.

Comment: I tried this in BaretailPro, which I'm using to filter my logs, and it doesn't work. It does work in RegExBuddy with test data. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Either your "real" data in your logs doesn't quite match your test data, or BaretailPro has a somewhat nonstandard regexp. You might try changing `S OZN` to `S\sOZN` and see if it makes any difference (maybe that's not a normal space there). If not, try changing `\s` to just blank and `\d` to `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 0):

based on your trial this pattern should solve it `S OZN.*?(CME 2 \d+ 1 \d+ 1)`